# Wrong output with the N Queen

Tags: c, algorithm, chess

So I have to do a modified version of the N queen problem, where we are given an initial configuration of the chess board filled with pawns, and we need to find the maximum number of queens we can have so that they don't attack each other. The input consists of an integer in the first line giving the dimension of the board ( NxN) and n lines defining the setup of the chess board.The characters will be either a ‘p’ (meaning there is already a pawn in that location) or an ‘e’ (meaning that location is empty).

For example, for this input,

```
5
epepe
ppppp
epepe
ppppp
epepe
```

the output will be 9.

Here is my code, everything seems clear, but I don't see why it doesnt give the correct output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

/* function headers */
void do_case(int);
int solve(char **,int,int);
int canPlace(char **,int,int,int);

/* Global vars */
int queens;

int main(void)
{
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
getchar();
while( n != 0 )
{
    do_case(n);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();
}
return 0;
}

void do_case(int n)
{
int i,j; //counters for input

//board configuration allocation
char **configuration = (char **)malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
for(i = 0 ; i < n ;i++ ) 
    configuration[i] =(char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char));

queens = 0;

//get input
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{

    for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        scanf("%c",&configuration[i][j]);
    }
    getchar();
}

//solve
solve(configuration,n,0);
printf("%d \n",queens);




}

//recursive solver 
int solve(char **configuration,int N,int col)
{
int i,j;
//base case
if( col >= N )
    return 1;

//consider this column
//try placing queen in non blocked spot in all rows 
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{

    if ( configuration[i][col] == 'e' && canPlace(configuration,N,i,col) )
    {
        //Place queen in configuration[i][col]
        configuration[i][col] = 'q';
        queens++;

        //recursion on the rest
        if( solve(configuration,N,col + 1) == 1 )
        {
            return 1;
        }

        //backtrack
        configuration[i][col] = 'e'; 
        queens--;

    }
}

return 0;

}


//this function check if  queen can be placed
int canPlace(char **configuration,int N, int row, int col)
{
int i, j;

/* Check this row on left side */
for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    if (configuration[row][i] == 'q')
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

/* Check upper diagonal on left side */
for (i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--)
{
    if ( configuration[i][j] == 'q')
    {

        return 0;
    }
}

/* Check lower diagonal on left side */
for (i = row, j = col; j >= 0 && i < N; i++, j--)
{
    if (configuration[i][j] == 'q')
    {

        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: No check for column in `canPlace()`, nor upper left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your code outputs 0 because it requires that we place exactly one queen in every column, which is not the case in your example.

That said, there are multiple problems with the algorithm (and I don't claim the list is complete, though it may be):

1. The code does not consider every possibility: it will only find the first possible arrangement, and then quit searching after a single "if( col >= N ) return 1;". Instead, it should go like "if( col >= N ) update the best possible value of queens in a separate variable, then return 0 to continue searching".
2. In the line "if( solve(configuration,N,col + 1) == 1 )", the code assumes there can not be two queens in a single column. The call should use `col` instead of `col + 1`, and somehow account for where we stopped at the current column.
3. To allow columns without queens, an unconditional call to "solve(configuration,N,col + 1)" should be placed somewhere in the solve function.
4. When we allow item 2, the function canPlace should be modified to also check the column.
5. The loops of canPlace should break whenever a pawn is found.

Answer (score 0):

With pawns blocking the way, you shouldn't just move on to the next column because you can place more queens in the same column.  You should modify your code to pass both a row and a column when you recurse, and only move to the next square, not the next column.

Also, it looks like your algorithm finds the first solution instead of the best solution.  The original queens problem only cared about 1 possible solution, but with the modified problem, you need to make sure you check all solutions and remember the best one.

Also, your `canPlace` function is wrong.  It doesn't account for pawns at all.